# Как сделать паузу между API запросами к ВКонтакте?

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Так уж сложилось что в цикле `do while` отправляються запросы к `API` Вконтакте, как сделать паузу между этими запросами?

Запросы отправляю спомощью `file_get_contents`

Вот собственно Весь код

```
do
{

$response = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=".$myrow_table_likes["type"]."&owner_id=".$myrow_table_likes["owner_id"]."&item_id=".$myrow_table_likes["item_id"]."&filter=likes");
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
if (!in_array($user_uid, $resp['response']['users'])) 
{
echo $myrow_table_likes["id"]."No likes<br>";   
}




}
while($myrow_table_likes = mysql_fetch_array($result_bd_likes));
```

Comment: [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usleep.php)

Comment: @Etki Пробовал, все тупо виснет а потом пролетает в одно мгновение

Comment: вы точно помещали его внутрь do?

Comment: @Etki Изменил Вопрос, внем написал Код, посмотрите.

Comment: для `file_get_contents` лучше контекст указывать с хидером *connection: close* (вроде так), иначе рискуете получить за доли секунды ответ и ждать еще секунд 30 манны небесной

Comment: @ВОРОН Первый раз встречаюсь с connection: close Как то польвотся им?

Comment: `$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList",false,$context);`

Comment: @ExileeD И че, прям в цикл вставлять или как, я чет недоганяю.

Comment: А почему бы не сложить все данные из бд в один массив, а потом  сделать запрос на метод `execute`, в котором можно безболезненно писать цикл `while` с этими данными без всяких sleep ?

Answer (score 1):

Как смог портировал для вас из python в php [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm)

этот код отправляет 20 сообщений с частотой 5 за 10 секунд:

```
<?php
$start = time();


$rate = 5.0; // $rate Сообщений
$per  = 10.0; // за $per секунд
$allowance = $rate; // сколько сначала можно отправить
$last_check = time(); // floating-point, e.g. usec accuracy. Unit: seconds

for($i = 0; $i < 20;) {
  $current = time();
  $time_passed = $current - $last_check;
  $last_check = $current;
  $allowance += $time_passed * ($rate / $per);

  if ($allowance > $rate) {
    $allowance = $rate; // throttle
  }

 if ($allowance < 1.0) {
  sleep(1);
  continue;
 } else {
    $i++;
    echo "working! elapsed: ".(time() - $start).PHP_EOL;
    $allowance -= 1.0;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант.
Перед запросом ставим

```
sleep(3);
```